# What does it mean - "to derive" operation from some existing one on a particular set?

Tags: soft-question, universal-algebra

> On the set $S = \{0, 1 \}$ let $f : S^3 \mapsto S$. Ternary operator $f(a, b, c)$ evaluates to $0$ when at least two arguments equal $0$; otherwise it returns $1$. One can form various terms in a symbolic operation $f$. An example: $f'(a, b, c, d, e) = f(a, f(b, c, d), e)$ and then evaluate these in the algebra $(S, f)$ **to get operations on $S$ derived from $f$**.

The thing which is not quite obvious, is how one might "derive" operations from $f$? Say, I want "to derive" an unary or binary operation (no matter what they will do, just the fact that none would be a $S^3 \mapsto S$ mapping). The only way I see to achieve that seems to be insane: I could factor $g(a, b)$ from $f(a, b, c)$ by... ignoring $c$. But it sounds so impractical, that I can't believe such a nonsense should be considered as a valid solution.

So, probably, there exist some another way "to derive" non-$f$ operations on the set $S$? Or did I misunderstood the entire "to derive" concept?

Comment: If $f$ is a ternary operation, then $(a,b)\mapsto f(a,a,f(b,a,a))$ and $a\mapsto f(a,a,a)$ are a binary and a unary operation derived from $f$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez that's genius! You did exactly what I called "insane": ignored the other parameters.

Comment: A concrete example is that if you have an associative algebra, then the commutator $[a,b]=ab-ba$ is a derived operation: it is an operation constructed from the operations given on the algebra you start with —in this case, from the sum and the product.

Comment: I did not ignore any parameters.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I mean, "substituted $c$ with $a$ or $b$". "Ignored" is not the best word to describe the solution.

Comment: Solutions to what?

Comment: However, taking only the example to learn the intended meaning of "to derive" in the context, it would sound reasonable that the author only considers $(2n+1)$ary operations as derived if they are of the form $(x_1,\ldots, x_{2n+1})\mapsto g(x_1,\ldots, x_{k-1},f(x_k,x_{k+1},x_{k+2}), x_{k+3},\ldots, x_{2n+1})$ where $g$ is (recursively) a derived $(2n-1)$ary function ...